# Image downloaded with wget has size of 4 bytes

Tags: image, http, unix, curl, wget

I have a problem with downloading certain image.

I'm trying to download image and save it on disk.

Here is the wget command, that I'm using and it works perfectly fine with almost every image. (code above works fine with this url)

```
wget -O test.gif http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/animation_example/lena_anim2.gif
```

Almost, becouse when I try to download image from this url: http://sklepymuzyczne24.pl/_data/ranking/686/e3991/ranking.gif

It fails. Downloaded file size is 4 bytes. I tried doing this using curl instead of wget, but the results are the same.

I think that the second image (the one not working) might be somehow generated (the image automatically changes, depending on store reviews). I belive that it has something to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some kind of misconfiguration on the server side. It won't return the image unless you specify that you accept gzip compressed content. Most web browsers nowadays do this by default, so the image is working fine in browser, but for wget or curl you need to add accept-encoding header manually. This way you will get gzip compressed image. Then you can pipe it to gunzip and get a normal, uncompressed image.

You could save the image using:

```
wget --header='Accept-Encoding: gzip' -O- http://sklepymuzyczne24.pl/_data/ranking/686/e3991/ranking.gif | gunzip - > ranking.gif
```